# autofac single instance per requesting type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have the following c# classes in a asp.net web api 2 project:
`WebService1` which has a dependency on `IHttpClientWrapper`
`WebService2` which has a dependency on `IHttpClientWrapper`

how can I register autofac so that every time `webService1` is resolved it gets the same instance of `HttpClientWrapper` and `webService2` gets the same instance of `HttpClientWrapper`. However each single instance of HttpClientWrapper is only shared amongst types objects with the same type.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you try to have "single instance per dependency".

There is no such functionality out-of-the-box in Autofac, but it's possible to do so e.g. with following registartions:

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpClientWrapper>().Named<IHttpClientWrapper>("WebService1").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<HttpClientWrapper>().Named<IHttpClientWrapper>("WebService2").SingleInstance();

builder.Register(c => new WebService1(c.ResolveNamed<IHttpClientWrapper>("WebService1"))).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => new WebService2(c.ResolveNamed<IHttpClientWrapper>("WebService2"))).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Now, everytime you resolve or inject `WebService1` or `WebService2` you get the same instance of `IHttpClientWrapper` per each WebService.